# Unable to suggest edits on meta sites with mobile app

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, per-site-meta, mobile-app

When using the Stack Exchange iOS app, the **edit** button for suggesting edits appears to be missing when viewing posts from a per-site meta.

[image]

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPad mini 2G (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3 (Build 14E277)

Comment: I didn't notice that, while per-site meta posts have an edit button in the browser, it's always greyed out. Closing question as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per-site Metas do not allow suggested edits for anything but tag wikis, so the button is appropriately hidden. You need to gain full editing privileges to edit anything on these Metas.